# can't really manage a map of <Float,Object> (EDITED)

Tags: java, floating-point

I have a

```
   map<Float,Object>.
```

I need it store valuse like

0.01 ->ObjA
0.02 ->ObjB

and sometimes

0.001 ->ObjA
0.002 ->ObjB (three digits after the dot)

I thought it would be easy.
But I have notice that when I calculate simple calculation with the float
I sometimes get stuff like this.

0.09998
0.02001  -----     instead of  (0.01, 0.02)

I know that float isnt that good for that usage so I have tried double and clearly I got a map filled with
0.0999999998
0.0200000001
naturally.

So I think I should round it. but it is not that easy since I dont know to which size.

sometimes it should be 0.03 and sometimes 0.3.
Thanks for your assistance.

---

---

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers. I think my problem is that I get 5.00001 instead of 5 . not that I enter 5.000001 to a map. I would like to round the float and each time to the best value I can find . and since it is alwas 0.0000000X or 0.999999X I think It should be easy. But I haven't figured it out yet.

---

Comment: I think the problem here it's not related to the map but to how you get the value of the keys of the map. How are these computed?

Comment: A-ha . you are correct. (as I have added in the edit ). you can even try to do 0.0001f+0.00045f and you will get surprises every time you calculate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
Map<BigDecimal, Object>
```

BigDecimal will allow you to define floating point values exactly.

Comment: Well, it will allow you to specify decimal values exactly. Double and Float are exact as well - but only for values which can be expressed by those types. Likewise BigDecimal can't represent 1/3 exactly. You shouldn't think of Float/Double as being approximate and BigDecimal as being accurate/exact - you should think about the values that can be represented exactly in each type.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you might want `Map<BigDecimal, Object>` if you're performing operations which are logically "accurate" within decimal arithmetic.

Alternatively, you might want a `Map<Integer, Object>` where 0.01 would map to 10, 0.001 would map to 1 etc. It's hard to know for sure without more information on what you're trying to do - but using `Float` or `Double` as the key in a map is likely to give you problems in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with accurate values use [java.math.BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of Float or Double (the API is a bit obscure).

Answer (score 0):

Float number can't represent all decimal numbers. That's the reason.

A clear example is 0.1, this number **can't** be written in a float, and that's why you get that number, it's your 0.1

My suggestion? Don't use float as keys, for a single 0.000001 you can miss something that **is** in your list

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers usually work with absolute or relative tolerances rather than values:
"I want this object when a float is between X and Y or X +/- Y."

If that's the case for you, I'd recommend trying another approach - this won't do.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use float (or doubles, or even BigDecimals) as keys. You will have unexpected errors, specially if you create keys making operations.
If you want a number for key, and you can handle some accuracy errors, use a Map and use your original floats * 10000 as keys. Even better, create a class CustomMap that wraps a Map, and implement only `put(float key, Object value){ map.put(10000 * key, value)}` and get(float), if you don't need the whole Map semantic.